# Function with same name as property swift: .first(where: ...)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

For  `var myArray:[[String:Any]]` Xcode lets me autocomplete

```
 myArray.first(where:{$0["name"] == "John Doe"})
```

but then doesn't let me compile it with an error "Cannot call value of non-function type '[String:Any]?'"

So anotherwords, swift can't figure out that I'm looking for the method `first(where:_)` instead of the no param version `.first`. What gives?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Xcode was giving the wrong message for this error. it was a simple type thing. You can't compare an `Any` to a `String`

```
 myArray.first(where:{$0["name"] == "John Doe"})
```

should have been:

```
  myArray.first(where:{
     guard let name $0["name"] as? String else {return false}
     return name == "John Doe"
  })
```

Comment: You can write it as `myArray.first(where:{$0["name"] as? String == "John Doe"})`

Comment: @JoeDaniels This is why you don't use Dictionaries for storing data structures with static keys like this :p